# Why is a template<typename...> not recognized as instantiatable through template<template<typename> typename>?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, variadic-templates

I'm trying to arbitrarily "bind" template parameters but have run into an elegance problem.

To cut straight to the underlying problem, gcc 6.2 has a problem with the following but logically I see no issue with it...

```
template<template<typename, typename> P, typename A, typename B>
struct foo {
    static constexpr bool value = P<A, B>::value;
};

template<typename...Ts>
struct bar {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

... `foo` given `bar` such as `foo<bar, void, void>` should result in the instantiation of `bar<void, void>` (which is valid), who's `value` member is `true` and therefore `foo<bar, void, void>::value` is likewise `true`. *Effectively*, this *should* (in my mind) result in instantiated structs conceptually akin to...

```
struct bar<void, void> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

struct foo<bar, void, void> {
    static constexpr bool value = bar<void, void>::value; //which is true
};
```

You can see this concept in action (or rather the error) here https://godbolt.org/g/lT9umg.

Back to the begining now, first I tried the following...

```
template<typename...>
struct type_list { };

template<template<typename...> typename Tmpl, typename...Ts>
struct bind_template {
    template<typename...Us>
    using type = Tmpl<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template<template<typename> typename Predicate, typename...Ts>
struct has_matching_type {
    private:
        template<template<typename> typename, typename, typename=void>
        struct helper: std::false_type { };
        template<template<typename> typename P, typename U, typename...Us>
        struct helper<P, type_list<U, Us...>, typename std::enable_if<P<U>::value>::type>: std::true_type { };
        template<template<typename> typename P, typename U, typename...Us>
        struct helper<P, type_list<U, Us...>, typename std::enable_if<!P<U>::value>::type>: helper<P, type_list<Us...>> { };
    public:
        static constexpr bool value = helper<Predicate, type_list<Ts...>>::value;
};

template<typename T, typename...Ts>
using has_type = has_matching_type<bind_template<std::is_same, T>::template type, Ts...>;
```

Later I might try to instantiate through `has_type<T, Ts...>` such as...

```
cout << has_type<long, int, bool, long, float>::value << endl;
```

However, as I pointed out gcc 6.2.0 complains because it doesn't seem to recognize that, once resolution is done, the template instantiation is pragmatically equivalent.

Simply knowing the number of template parameters and specializing for that exact number solves the problem. If I specialize `bound_template` keeping `std::is_same<LHS, RHS>` in mind...

```
template<template<typename, typename> typename Tmpl, typename T>
struct bind_template<Tmpl, T> {
    template<typename U>
    using type = Tmpl<T, U>;
};
```

... we suddenly compile and evaluate compile-time no problem because gcc sees `bind_template<std::is_same, long>::type` as taking one type parameter exactly.

Obviously, abstracting this concept out to allow for any template parameters, such as integral constants and not just types, is a fundamental issue regardless of compiler. Simply focusing on types for a minute though, my question is multiple:

1. Am I missing something here conceptually and the compiler is actually doing exactly what should be obvious to me?
2. If not, is this in violation of C++11 standards, not directed by standards, or is it a compiler dependency?
3. Is there some elegant way I can get around this regardless of the answers to my first two questions?

Functionally, the real question (particularly if this is an unavoidable issue in C++11) is...

### Is there some elegant way I can abstractly bind templates without having to specialize for every case (the simplest here being *n* number of types)?

Just being able to get an answer to questions 1 or 3 would be great. Question 3 is the most important because at the end of the day it's what works that matters.

Obviously, I can specialize (as shown above). A big problem though is that even the following doesn't seem to work (at least according to [this online compiler](http://cpp.sh/9lrwd))...

```
template<template<typename...> class Tmpl, typename... Ts>
struct bind_helper {
    template<typename... Us>
    struct type: Tmpl<Ts..., Us...> { };
    template<typename A>
    struct type<A>: Tmpl<Ts..., A> { };
    template<typename A, typename B>
    struct type<A, B>: Tmpl<Ts..., A, B> { };
    template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
    struct type<A, B, C>: Tmpl<Ts..., A, B, C> { };
};
```

This means that, not only would I have to generate a bunch of parameters, but I'd have to match the outer parameters as well via complete `bind_template` specialization. This quickly becomes (actually is) a binomial problem.

Extending this concept further (but still keeping to types), I was planning to next implement "placeholders" the same way `std::bind` uses placeholders (which would have worked rather elegantly because I would have just peeled and rejoined the list at the index). Obviously this is too much of a mess to proceed without a more abstract approach available.

Answer (score 10):

This is fixed in C++17. Specifically, from [14.3.3 "Template template arguments", paragraph 3:](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template#3)

> ```
> template<class T> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<class T, class U = T> class B { /* ... */ };
> template<class ... Types> class C { /* ... */ };
> template<auto n> class D { /* ... */ };
> template<template<class> class P> class X { /* ... */ };
> template<template<class ...> class Q> class Y { /* ... */ };
> template<template<int> class R> class Z { /* ... */ };
>
> X<A> xa;            // OK
> X<B> xb;            // OK
> X<C> xc;            // OK
> Y<A> ya;            // OK
> Y<B> yb;            // OK
> Y<C> yc;            // OK
> Z<D> zd;            // OK
> ```

The relevant example here is `X<C>`. This works in g++ 7 with the flag `-std=c++1z`.

C++14 specifies that the example above is ill-formed:

> ```
> template<class T> class A { /∗ ... ∗/ };
> template<class T, class U = T> class B { /∗ ... ∗/ };
> template <class ... Types> class C { /∗ ... ∗/ };
> template<template<class> class P> class X { /∗ ... ∗/ };
> template<template<class ...> class Q> class Y { /∗ ... ∗/ };
> X<A> xa; // OK
> X<B> xb; // ill-formed: default arguments for the parameters of a template argument are ignored
> X<C> xc; // ill-formed: a template parameter pack does not match a template parameter
> ```

The change came in late 2016 from the paper [DR: Matching of template template-arguments excludes compatible templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html). The change was applied in [this commit from November](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/4422e4105ce477ed325edc9535a6bf2fa9b2ed29). The issue has been [known by the committee since 1999 or before](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4457.html#150).

Comment: An editorial comment: this is why type systems should be formally specified. 14.3.3 includes the following prose: *"Each function template has a single function parameter whose type is a specialization of X with template arguments corresponding to the template parameters from the respective function template where, for each template parameter PP in the template parameter list of the function template, a corresponding template argument AA is formed."* Good gravy!

Comment: That seems to answer questions 1 ("No, you're not conceptually missing anything") and 2 ("The issue was not addressed by standards until C++14 (disallowed) and C++17 (allowed) [potentially]"). Any help with question part 3 (the most important question)?

Comment: You haven't really explained what the problem you're trying to solve, only the method you used to solve it. To question #3, "Any way around this?", I can only answer "The flag -std=c++1z" without further details of what your problem is, rather than just your attempted solution.

Comment: You should probably include the wording that changed (which is normative) in addition to the examples that changed (which aren't).

Comment: @jbapple (and Barry) Sorry, I thought people could see where I was going with that. Hmmm... okay, let me flush that problem out more. Basically it just comes down to "How can I implement `bind_template` without having to manually specialize for N number of types" (aka, elegantly). I moved a lot of stuff around trying to make the underlying problem more clear but I might have mucked up the fundamental question in the process. Also, I didn't say this last night, but excellent answer to parts 1 and 2. Thanks.

Comment: @jbapple Added more detail near the bottom of the post. Any ideas/questions on that? That was originally the question but I also wanted to know why gcc was barfing over something that made sense to me and no one was viewing this--let alone commenting--so it turned more into a "standards" question than a practical one.

Comment: @jbapple Also, while I think of it, let me point out that switching to C++17 isn't a solution as C++ compilers have only in the last couple of years caught up to C++11 (still with some major holes [have you tried using redhat's STL on real-world servers that can't update past gcc 4.x? Go ahead and try to test if something matches specific "is_trivially_*" conditions]), and C++17 isn't even out of draft yet. It's not portable, stable, or practical for production code. While targeting c++1z is interesting and fun for homebew stuff, it's not even close to shop-ready.

Answer (score 3):

Before C++17, this code is ill-formed as-is, due to an unfortunate language defect as mentioned in [jbapple's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42084008/2069064).

A C++11-conforming solution would be to switch from using metafunctions everywhere to using metafunction classes everywhere. A metafunction class, from Boost.MPL's definition, would be a type that has a template alias named `apply`. Which we can invoke thusly:

```
template <class MFC, class... Ts>
using apply_t = typename MFC::template apply<Ts...>;
```

We can lift a template into a metafunction class via:

```
template <template <typename...> class Z>
struct quote {
    template <class... Args>
    using apply = Z<Args...>;
};
```

Then let's rewrite `bind_template` to take a metafunction class instead of a template:

```
template <class MFC, class... Ts>
struct bind_template {
    template <class... Us>
    using apply = apply_t<MFC, Ts..., Us...>;
};
```

And then rewrite `has_matching_type` to take a metafunction class instead of a template:

```
template<class Predicate, class... Ts>
struct has_matching_type {
private:
    template<class>
    struct helper: std::false_type { };

    template<typename U, typename...Us>
    struct helper<type_list<U, Us...>>
        : std::conditional<
            apply_t<Predicate, U>::value,
            std::true_type,
            helper<type_list<Us...>>
            >::type
     { };

public:
    static constexpr bool value = helper<type_list<Ts...>>::value;
};

template<class T, class... Ts>
using has_type = has_matching_type<bind_template<quote<std::is_same>, T>, Ts...>;
```

And now your initial `has_type<long, int, bool, long, float>::value` is `true`, even in C++11.

Comment: Pretty nice solution! That would work for anything that takes templates that I wrote (like `has_matching_type`). Sadly it wouldn't work for third party templates that takes a template as a parameter, but in reality it's probably not a big deal and wouldn't come up too much. I'll let the question sit for a couple more days and if no one comes along with a perfectly generic solution, the bounty's definitely yours. I wish I could split it up and give part to @jbapple because that was a fantastic partial answer.

Comment: Well, the bounty's yours. Again, sadly it can't be shared. Good answers all around.